# Why can't I use data augmentation with a pretrained convnet?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, beginner, data-augmentation

Reading Deep Learning with Python by François Chollet. In section 5.3.1, we've instantiated a pretrained convnet, VGG16, and are given two options to proceed:

> A) Running the convolutional base over your dataset, recording its
>   output to a Numpy array on disk, and then using this data as input to
>   a standalone, densely connected classifier similar to those you saw in
>   part 1 of this book. This solution is fast and cheap to run, because
>   it only requires running the convolutional base once for every input
>   image, and the convolutional base is by far the most expensive part of
>   the pipeline. But for the same reason, **this technique won’t allow you**
>   **to use data augmentation**.
>
> B) Extending the model you have (conv_base) by adding Dense layers on
>   top, and running the whole thing end to end on the input data. **This**
>   **will allow you to use data augmentation**, because every input image
>   goes through the convolutional base every time it’s seen by the model.
>   But for the same reason, this technique is far more expensive than the
>   first.

Why can't I use data augmentation to generate more training data from existing training samples then go with option A? Seems like I can run the VGG16 base over my augmented dataset and use the output as the input to a standalone densely connected classifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in stats.stackexchange.com. Hopefully this helps anyone else with the same question.

[feature extraction: freezing convolutional base vs. training on extracted features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331162/feature-extraction-freezing-convolutional-base-vs-training-on-extracted-featur/366465?newreg=4f0695a759ea4446ad76161b0e495093)